# How to delete traces.txt

Tags: android, stack-trace, logcat, trace, android-logcat

```
E/dalvikvm(5717): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Is a directory
```

Regarding to this ErrorMessage in LogCat I would like to delete the traces.txt directory and create a file. Where can I find it?

Comment: This is only something you can fix on a rooted device, or by installing an Android build where this configuration mistake is corrected.

Answer (score 2):

commandline:

> $ adb shell
>
> $ cd data/anr/
>
> $ rmdir traces.txt

Comment: I get and permission denied error. (I started cmd as administrator)

Comment: May be the user on the mobile has not enough permissions... Is your phone rooted?

Comment: You can't obviously remove a directory using `rm`, but `rmdir` works.

Comment: I am getting permission denied as well.

Comment: This answer isn't incorrect, as it literally responds to the request.  However it will probably only work on an unsecured device (or emulator) where adbd runs as root.

Answer (score 0):

Since traces.txt is a directory, you probably want to do rmdir traces.txt

Comment: traces.txt IS A FILE not a directory